# How do you wash a Kittel?

Tags: how-to, cleaning, kittel

I have a cotton-polyester kittel from Ben's Tallit Shop (everyone's favorite, right?) Here's the description: http://tzitzit.tallit-shop.com/pleated-kittel/

Does anyone know how to wash them? Do I wash it like a normal cotton garment? Also, will it shrink? (I hope it does.)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about cleaning a garment, not about anything particularly Jewish. Is there a stack for laundry?

Comment: Vote to keep open because it is about how to care for a garment that is a דבר המיוחד לתפילה. This isn't any different than any of the questions about how to make lighting for a sukka, etc. etc.

Comment: I take mine to the dry cleaners.

Comment: @yishai Until he explains why this garment may be unique in its laundry needs, it remains a weak question.

Comment: We have a question here about cleaning tzitzit, this is fine. I wash mine in the machine, and you can tell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I always bring my *kittel* to the dry cleaner. It always comes back nice and clean (and freshly ironed).

Comment: I've been doing just that for years. Recommendation - if you can get a kittel with an attached (sewn on) belt, if possible,. Otherwise, you risk losing it. Not that it's the worst thing to happen, but I find that kittels tend to be big, and having the belt helps quite a bit, and it looks nicer too.

Comment: @DanF consider keeping the belt at home when the kittel goes to the cleaners.

Comment: @yEz Duh... It's a simple solution, if you want to wash and iron the belt yourself :-) The attached ones, though, is a good solution.

Comment: @DanF, an alternative would be a white gartel, as it should also be more of a "one size fits most" solution if you get a new kittel or let it out.